# c++, how is trailing comma not an error and what happens? Foo x, y,;

Tags: c++, syntax, undefined-behavior

Someone pointed out to me that I had what looks like a typo in some c++ code:

```
protected:
    Foo  x, y,;
```

I would have thought the trailing comma would be an error, but apparently it isn't? Is this undefined, or what happens? Presumably something bad, since a code-checker program complained about it.

Comment: Could be a compiler extension - which compiler are you using?

Comment: The comma is probably wrong though.

Comment: It's to make code generation easier. Doubt it's standard.

Comment: Which compiler were you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant grammar production is in §9.2:

```
member-declarator-list:
  member-declarator
  member-declarator-list , member-declarator
```

The comma is only allowed to separate the declarators (names). *member-declarator* may not itself contain a comma.

**EDIT:** here is *member-declarator*… it's not quite as self-contained, the syntax for declarators is in general a cobweb.

```
member-declarator:
  declarator virt-specifier-seq(opt) pure-specifier(opt)
  declarator brace-or-equal-initializer(opt)
  identifier(opt) attribute-specifier-seq(opt) : constant-expression
```

Incorrect grammar is not undefined behavior; a compiler allowing a misplaced comma has a bug. Rejecting that sort of thing is a requirement of the standard.

Note, trailing commas are allowed in enumeration definitions and brace-initializers. I think both cases were added by C++11 to simplify writing source code generators. (The preprocessor, which most often gets that job, has a tough time even with such simple requirements.) Typically a simple generator might avoid creating declarations with multiple names, because due to the complicated grammar, it's a can of worms. On the other hand, an empty declaration consisting of `;` is allowed, as is a semicolon after a member function definition.

Comment: Can you post member-declarator too?

Comment: @Pubby ask and ye shall receive… but it just references a bunch of other high-level constructs.

Comment: The grammar of *init-declarator-list* is similar allowing trailing comma, yet GCC doesn't compile trailing comma.

Comment: @Nawaz In the grammar summary appendix of N3485, I don't see a trailing comma in init-declarator-list, it's exactly the same as member-declarator-list but with init-declarator subsituted for member-declarator.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Now your answer is complete, as it explicitly says *"Incorrect grammar is not undefined behavior; a compiler allowing a misplaced comma has a bug."* which is consistent with my understanding of declarator syntax. +1

Comment: I do have the C++11 flag on, maybe that has an effect. Anyway, sounds like you mean it is ignored by some compilers and reported as error by others.

Answer (score 1):

My observations

GCC 4.6.2:

```
void myFunc()
{
  int x, y, ; // <-- Syntax error
}
```

But

```
class MyClass
{
  int x, y,; // <-- No error (one extra comma) but last comma is ignored
};
```

MSVC 2008:

> Both of them make errors

OpenWatcom 1.8:

> Both of them make errors